# Redirect domain to subfolder with some specific pages fallback

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, fallback

I need to change website domain from www.domain.com to www.newdomain.com/en but I also need to specify some pages from old website to new website like www.domain.com/page to www.newdomain.com/en/subfolder/subfolder/page.

Last thing should be great keeping one subfolder path of old website free of redirect like www.domain.com/admin in order to keep backend access to old website.

What would you suggest me to add to old site htaccess file in order to achieve that with a sort of fallback mechanism for specifc pages and whole domain to subdirectory?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following 301 redirect to your oldsite/htaccess :

```
Redirect 301 / http://newdomain.com/en/subfolder/subfolder/
```

This will redirect all requests from your old site to the subfolder in your new site

Edit : as per your comment,
to exclude a specific path from the redirection, you may use RedirectMatch

```
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/((?!page1|page2).*) http://newdomain.com/en/subfolder/subfolder/$1
```

This will not redirect **/page1** or **/page2** .

Comment: thank you but I don't need all request. I need all request from www.domain.com to www.newdomain.com/en except some specific pages like www.domain.com/page that in the new website has custom address like www.newdomain.com/en/subfolder/subfolder/page. How can I specify some custom url expception?

Comment: Ok thanks  that will redirect whole website to another domain subfolder path except the specified pages that won't be redirected. But how can I specify some pages of the old domain to be redirect to a specific new domain address?